# Add Excel Import to existing Acumatica Page - Without redefining the Data View

Tags: acumatica

I want to extend an Acumatica page and include the ability to import form Excel in a grid.
I understand that you can achieve this by adding PXImport to the data view and setting AllowUpload to the grid.

However, my concern is that I don't want to repeat the view definition in my extension. This is because, in case there is an Acumatica update and the view is updated, I don't want to always remember to check whether I need to update my view as well.

Is there a way to add a PXImport in an extension without having to repeat the View definition of the Base graph? Something similar to a 'CacheAttached' but for a Data View not a DAC.
Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to add a PXImport in an extension without having to
>   repeat the View definition of the Base graph? Something similar to a 'CacheAttached' but for a Data View not a DAC.

To my knowledge such feature doesn't exists. The most recent documentation (2019 R2) is still instructing to copy the original data view declaration and modify it if necessary:
https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=5312e75a-6f0a-4b2c-a28c-38da20782087